# What property does gnome use to group application windows?

Tags: gnome, launcher

I want to run two instances of a terminal emulator (urxvt) and have them appear as separate applications. I have two .desktop files and thus two entries in the launcher but when I launch the second one it gets grouped with the first.

I've tried changing the Name, GenericName, StartupWMClass, copying the executable, and passing the -name option to urxvt. None of those works.

I am not asking about switching between the instances with Alt-Tab.

Comment: With Firefox using the `--class` option to set wm_class works for me. With [urxvt, maybe `-name`](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=647303#p647303) can be used for a similar effect.

Comment: I've tried -name, it allows me to change the WM_CLASS to foo.URxvt but that still gets grouped.